# Extraction of Value from Text file and reporting sum

Tags: windows, logging, vbscript

I have a text file generated by a application, the file is called "ErrorLog.log"

The log reads (up to 300 records per day entered):

> Version 3.10
>  No Files Found
>  Total of 0 messages read
>  Total
>   Messages Sent: 0  \  Total Messages Received: 0
>  Last time
>   connected was 08\20\2013 at 08:17:50
>  Version 3.10
>  No Files
>   Found
>  Total of 0 messages read
>  Total Messages Sent: 0  \ 
>   Total Messages Received: 0
>  Last time connected was 08\20\2013 at
>   08:20:14
>  Version 3.10
>  No Files Found
>  Total of 0 messages
>   read
>  Total Messages Sent: 0  \  Total Messages Received: 0
>   Last time connected was 08\20\2013 at 08:30:14

What I really need is to get a sum of the "Total Messages Received" in the file. The file has do end of file text or anything like that.

I want to then take that number and:

1. Write it to a existing file called TransactionsDaily.txt
2. Email a message to my team saying "x messages were processed on 20 August 2013.".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = ".* Total Messages Received: (\d+)$"
re.IgnoreCase = True

msgCount = 0

Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\ErrorLog.log")
Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
  line = f.ReadLine
  If re.Test(line) Then msgCount = msgCount + CInt(re.Replace(line, "$1"))
Loop
f.Close

WScript.Echo msgCount
```